# Issue with Oozie job that takes output of multiple parents

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie

- I have three jobs(call them p1, p2 and p3) that take inputs from 3 diffrent directories in HDFS and writes the output into 3 diffect directoes respectively.
- The data availibility of the 3 input directories varies day by day. I mean those 3 input directories are asynchronously populated say anytime between 1 AM - 3 AM. But once the files are uploaded, a _DONEFLAG is created in each directories.
- The requirement is to start a job as soon as data is made available in it's respective directories.
- I have another job(call it c1) that takes the input data from the output of p1, p2 and p3 hence c1 can only start when all 3 parent jobs have been completed.

Is there a way to address above situation with oozie (coordinators , workflows and bundles)? these are daily jobs and the input directories have the date pattrens. In my understanding I can't fork P1, p2 and p3 in parallel in single workflow as all 3 are dependent on their respective data availibilities. If I write 3 separate workflows and coordinators for each parent job(p1, p2, p3) then how would I make the c1 job start only when all the 3 input jobs are completed? I'm using oozie v4. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Can you accommodate jobs p1,p2 and p3 adding additional file like _DONEFLAG after there completion in their respective output directory or any other directory in case there isn't any output directory.

Then create another coordinator for your job c1 which will listen on availability of flag for each of the jobs p1,p2 and p3 and then start.

This is one way and has benefit of loosely coupled jobs.

You may also want to look at "**Data Pipelining**" as described in oozie docs for coordinators. Although its quite close to my suggestion above : https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.1/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html

There may be other ways but these are two I could think of.